# Can/should app servers be used also as web servers, for small applications?

Tags: angular, tomcat, server, webserver

More specifically, is there any disadvantage to deploying an angular app on a Java servlet container like Tomcat or Weblogic, as opposed to on a dedicated http server like nginx or apache-http?

Answer (score 2):

Running in a JVM will cost more in memory and you will see stop-the-world pauses. There are probably other disadvantages (cost of deployment, cost of licensing for Weblogic,..)